# Google sign in appears every time after closing the app android

Tags: android, google-signin

I am trying to integrate google sign in with my app , which is working as desired . But when I am closing the app , it is asking to login again , which I dont want . I am trying to do silentSignIn but that is not helping out . I want user to see MainActivity once they logged in .

```
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;

import com.facebook.CallbackManager;
import com.facebook.FacebookSdk;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.Auth;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInAccount;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInOptions;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.Scopes;
import com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.OptionalPendingResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.ResultCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.Scope;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.Status;
import com.google.android.gms.plus.Plus;
import com.google.android.gms.plus.model.people.Person;

public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {

    private static final String TAG = "LoginActivity";
    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    private static final int RC_SIGN_IN = 9001;
    private ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;

    private String mFullName ;
    private String mEmail ;
    private String mAccountId ;
    private int mGender ;
    private String mRights;
    private String mBirthDay ;

    //CallbackManager callbackManager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

        findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button).setOnClickListener(this);

        GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                .requestEmail()
                .build();

        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .enableAutoManage(this /* FragmentActivity */, this /* OnConnectionFailedListener */)
                .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso)
                .addApi(Plus.API)
                .addScope(new Scope(Scopes.PROFILE))
                .addScope(new Scope(Scopes.EMAIL))
                .build();

        SignInButton signInButton = (SignInButton) findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button);
        signInButton.setSize(SignInButton.SIZE_STANDARD);
        signInButton.setScopes(gso.getScopeArray());

        /*FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
        callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();*/


    }

    /**
     * Called when a view has been clicked.
     *
     * @param v The view that was clicked.
     */
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.sign_in_button:
                signIn();
                break;
            /*case R.id.sign_out_button:
                signOut();
                break;
            case R.id.disconnect_button:
                revokeAccess();
*/              //  break;
        }
    }



    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        OptionalPendingResult<GoogleSignInResult> opr = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.silentSignIn(mGoogleApiClient);
        if (opr.isDone()) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Got cached sign-in");
            GoogleSignInResult result = opr.get();
            handleSignInResult(result);
        } else {
           showProgressDialog();
            opr.setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<GoogleSignInResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onResult(@NonNull GoogleSignInResult googleSignInResult) {
                    hideProgressDialog();
                    handleSignInResult(googleSignInResult);
                }
            });
        }


    }



    private void signIn() {
        Intent signInIntent = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(mGoogleApiClient);
        startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN);
    }

    /*public void getUserDetails(){
        GoogleSignInResult result = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data);
        GoogleSignInAccount acct = result.getSignInAccount();
        String personName = acct.getDisplayName();
        String personEmail = acct.getEmail();
        String personId = acct.getId();
        Uri personPhoto = acct.getPhotoUrl();

    }*/

    private void handleSignInResult(GoogleSignInResult result) {
        Log.d(TAG, "handleSignInResult:" + result.isSuccess());
        Log.d(TAG,"handleSignInResult Result : " + result);
        if (result.isSuccess()) {
// Signed in successfully, show authenticated UI.
            GoogleSignInAccount acct = result.getSignInAccount();
           // mStatusTextView.setText(getString(R.string.signed_in_fmt, acct.getDisplayName()));
            //updateUI(true);
            showSignedInUI();
        } else {
// Signed out, show unauthenticated UI.
            //updateUI(false);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
// Result returned from launching the Intent from GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(...);
        if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
            GoogleSignInResult result = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data);
            handleSignInResult(result);
            if(result.isSuccess()){
                GoogleSignInAccount acct = result.getSignInAccount();
                // Get account information
                mFullName = acct.getDisplayName();
                mEmail = acct.getEmail();
                mAccountId = acct.getId();
                Uri personPhoto = acct.getPhotoUrl();
                if (Plus.PeopleApi.getCurrentPerson(mGoogleApiClient) != null) {
                    Person currentPerson = Plus.PeopleApi.getCurrentPerson(mGoogleApiClient);
                    mGender = currentPerson.getGender();
                    mBirthDay = currentPerson.getBirthday();
                    mRights = currentPerson.getBraggingRights();
                }

                Log.d(TAG,"User Details : Name : " + mFullName + " Email : " + mEmail + " Account Id : " + mAccountId);
                Log.d(TAG,"Photo URL : " + personPhoto);
                Log.d(TAG, " Gender : " + mGender + " BirthDay : " + mBirthDay + " Rights : " + mRights);

                }
        }
    }

    private void signOut() {
        Auth.GoogleSignInApi.signOut(mGoogleApiClient).setResultCallback(
                new ResultCallback<Status>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResult(Status status) {
// [START_EXCLUDE]
                       // updateUI(false);
// [END_EXCLUDE]
                    }
                });
    }

    private void revokeAccess() {
        Auth.GoogleSignInApi.revokeAccess(mGoogleApiClient).setResultCallback(
                new ResultCallback<Status>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResult(Status status) {
// [START_EXCLUDE]
                        //updateUI(false);
                       // showSignedInUI();
// [END_EXCLUDE]
                    }
                });
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
// An unresolvable error has occurred and Google APIs (including Sign-In) will not
// be available.
        Log.d(TAG, "onConnectionFailed:" + connectionResult);
    }
    private void showProgressDialog() {
        if (mProgressDialog == null) {
            mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
            //mProgressDialog.setMessage(getString(R.string.loading));
            mProgressDialog.setMessage(getString(R.string.loading));
            mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
        }
        mProgressDialog.show();
    }
    private void hideProgressDialog() {
        if (mProgressDialog != null && mProgressDialog.isShowing()) {
            mProgressDialog.hide();
        }
    }

    private void showSignedInUI() {
        Log.d(TAG, "showSignedInUI: " + mGoogleApiClient.isConnected());
        if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
            //getProfileInformation();
            final Context context = this;
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, MapsActivity.class);

            startActivity(intent);
            finish();


        }
    }


}
```

Answer (score 1):

currently check the status using isConnected() and move on to map activity or  All you have to do is save a state in shared preferences or database saying the login has happened, and take him inside the app, once the login screen has opened

Answer (score 0):

if you want to see the `MainActivity` once the user is logged in, then remove the code at `onStart()`.